# $\left\{ 0,1 \right\}^{[0,1)}$ is not sequentially compact

Tags: general-topology

> $\left\{ 0,1 \right\}^{[0,1)}$ is not sequentially compact

Is this true? Looking for explanation.

**Note** : Here $\left\{ 0,1 \right\}^{[0,1)}$ denotes the set of functions with domain $[0,1)$ and range $\left\{ 0 , 1 \right\}$ i.e. the set of functions 
$$f_n : [0,1) \to \left\{ 0 , 1 \right\} $$

The discrete topology is used on this set $\left\{ 0 , 1 \right\}$ and the product topology is used on the set $\left\{ 0 , 1 \right\}^{[0,1)}$

Comment: What topology is defined on your set?

Comment: @M. Winter The discrete topology

Comment: You mean "the discrete topology on $\{0,1\}$, and the product topology on $\{0,1\}^{[0,1)}$", I believe.

Comment: Yes, Daniel Fischer. Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure you're not using the topology on the function space induced by the sup norm?

Comment: No, Kenny Wong. It's as Daniel Fischer corrected.

Comment: I'm still not sure if this works. The product topology is made for $[0,1)\times\{0,1\}$ and not for your set. Maybe @DanielFischer can explain how he meant this.

Comment: @M.Winter The product topology on $$\prod_{t\in [0,1)} \{0,1\}.$$

Comment: @DanielFischer Ah of course. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

(A bit old question, but my friend recently asked me the same question so I write a one here.)

Yes, it is true.

You can construct a non-convergent sequence ${f_n}$ as follows.
Each $x \in [0, 1)$ has a binary representation $x = 0.x_1 x_2 x_3 \cdots$ and if we avoid ones ending in a string of 1’s it is unique.

Let $f_n(x) = x_n$. If $f_{n_k} \to f$ then let $r \in [0, 1)$ be a real s.t. $f_{n_k} (r) = \frac{1+(-1)^k}{2}$. Obviously $f_{n_k}$’s are not eventually in the open neighborhood $\left\{f(r)\right\}\times\left\{0, 1\right\}^{[0, 1) \setminus \left\{r \right\}}$